# Wordpress wrong or different product redirect

Tags: wordpress

I have create a wordpress website but from 2-3 days i sufer a problem that when I click on a product then it opens a different product page like ex (open product - demo 1 and with right url it opens randomly product- demo 2-5)  and it happens only in Mobil screen not in desktop in desktop it works nicely but in Mobil it happens and I try 5 different mobils but it same happens

I you have a solution for this

Many thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.